# ds9 configuration issue

Tags: observational-astronomy, data-analysis, fits, ds9, visualization

I'm trying to use DS9 for X-ray image analysis. Before that I have to configure it for use, I need to click on option using web proxy.

[image: ds9 configuration screen shot]

Beside use internal web browser checkbox there should be another checkbox with name using web proxy that I have to check in to use this software specifically.

I using windows 11.

I tried to configure my system for proxy control pannel>Network and Internet>Internet Options>Connections>Lan settings then checked in at use a proxy server for your LAN.

Comment: do you have to use the internal web browser? it's possible that if you deselect that option then it'll use your default web browser, which will use your system's proxy setting